# Can't assign the 1st element of an array

Tags: c#

I made 2 arrays to store integers for my needs. 
Then I tried to assign the 1st elements of these arrays but it says "The name does not exists in the current conexts" . How is it even possible?

As these arrays are static, I tried to assign 0-index element in another class and it worked. But I need them to be assigned here.

```
class Program
{
    public static int[] coordinateX = new int[50];
    coordinateX[0] = 21;
    public static int[] coordinateY = new int[50];
    coordinateY[0] = 11;
}
```

Comment: Where is that code located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing class members with local variables, you can't have them as both.

You either need to use variable syntax in the method:

```
int[] coordinateX = new int[50];
coordinateX[0] = 21;
int[] coordinateY = new int[50];
coordinateY[0] = 11;
```

Or member syntax outside the method, which can include things like *access modifiers* (`public` `private`) the `static` (and other) *keywords*

```
public static int[] coordinateX = new int[50];

public static int[] coordinateY = new int[50];

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   coordinateX[0] = 21;

   coordinateY[0] = 11;
}
```

At this point, it's probably best to read the documentation.

[Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

```
public class Customer
{
   // Fields, properties, methods and events go here...
}
```

[Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // local variable and stuff here
}
```

Comment: I have attached snippet inside the class. It worked with just int variables but stopped when I turned them into arrays. Making a constructor to assign values worked for me but I don't clearly understand why didn't it work without it tho.

Comment: @Jinn You can call this in a class `coordinateY[0] = 11` and you cant put this `public static int[] coordinateX = new int[50]` in a method. i think you maybe confused about what worked and what didn't

Comment: I can't get your point. I called coordinateY[0] = 11 in a class as you say I can. And I didnt put public static int[] coordinateX = new int[50] in a method as you say I can't.

Comment: @Jinn `coordinateY[0] = 11` will not ever work in a class, it has to be in a method, its a variable assignment, C# syntax doesn't allow it at the class level

Answer (score 0):

Can you show more of your code?

If the above snippet is within a class then you need to define a function or constructor to change index 0 to a value:

E.g.

```
public class CName
{
    public static int[] coordinateX = new int[50];

    static CName()
    {
     coordinateX[0] = 21;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should probably be a static constructor rather than an instance constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed Thanks.

Comment: @Jinn Please up vote and mark as answered if this was useful :).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, initialization can be done along with the declaration or it can be done inside the constructor or any other functions.

**A class definition can only have declaration statements.**